# Multiple controller types were found that match the URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

I have different controllers

**ContentsController**

**NewsController**

etc.

In ContentsController I have method

```
[Route("~/{seoTitle}", Order = 10)]
public async Task<ActionResult> Show(string seoTitle)
```

NewsController

```
[Route("~/News", Order = 2)]
[Route("~/News/Page/{page}", Order = 1)]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int page = 1)
```

When I try go to page */News* I get error

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can
>   happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested
>   URL.
>
> The request has found the following matching controller types:

I understand why this happened. But how I can fix this, if I using route attributes?

Comment: Do these controllers have route prefixes? the tilde (~) is normally used to override route prefixes. If one is not used then there is no need to use the tilde.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809556/mvc5-attribute-routing-precedence-among-controllers

Comment: No they haven't route prefixes